# How would I make these google map buttons on my website, be linked to divs instead?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[A picture of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2WQk.png) 
[My code pen here](https://codepen.io/flame732/pen/LYpvYeW)I need to make the 2 buttons that are on the google map, to instead be the two divs that are next to eachother and make them clickable and have the same function as the two buttons on the map, so whenever it is clicked it goes to the specific location on the google map. The two buttons work on the map, but i dont want them on the map, I want them out and replaced to be clicked with the two divs on n the side. Thank you for the help.I included a link to my code below.

```css
/* MAP */
.map-section{
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.map-section h3{
  margin-left: 370px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #3B3358;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.map-item{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
  border-bottom: : 1px solid #E9E9E9;
  border-top: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
  border-left: 10px solid #ECB237;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left:370px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.map-item2{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
  border-bottom: : 1px solid #E9E9E9;
  border-top: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
  border-left: 10px solid #85ccff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left:370px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.map-section p{
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.map-item h4{
  color: #3B305A;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.map-item2 h4{
  color: #3B305A;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.map-item .fa-map-marker-alt{
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.map-item2 .fa-map-marker-alt{
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.map-item .fa-phone-alt{
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.map-item2 .fa-phone-alt{
  margin-right: 8px;
}


#map{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
/* END MAP */
```

```html
<section class="map-section">
    <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 align-items-center">
              <h3>Contact Us</h3>
              <div class="map-item">
                <h4>Van Nuys Office:</h4>
                <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> 14435 Hamlin St Ste 101 Van Nuys, CA 91401</p>
                <p><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>800-399-0860</p>
              </div>
              <div class="map-item2">
                <h4>El Monte Office:</h4>
                <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> 9814 E Garvey Ave Ste 9. El Monte, CA 91733</p>
                <p><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>800-573-9920</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 ">
              <div id="map" style="height:400px; width:100%"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: For some reason my code and codepen were not posted properly. Here is the link to my code pen https://codepen.io/flame732/pen/LYpvYeW

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please paste the code snippets in your question.

Comment: Also be aware that if you  use google buttons or facebook like buttons they will track anyone visiting that page. It may affect any GDPR issues.